Want to submit thesis to arxiv, but currently affiliated to another institute. What to do?
I want to publish my thesis made at university (A) to arXiv.org.
However, I am currently affiliated with another institute (university B). While the original thesis is written at A, do I mention the original or current institute in the paper? As arXiv imposed strict rules regarding the affiliations...
What do you suggest I do? Should I submit it with my current affiliation and mention the original or am I overthinking things?

First, congrats on finishing your thesis, and thanks for taking the time to upload it to arXiv!

What do you suggest I do? Should I submit it with my current affiliation and mention the original or am I overthinking things?

Yes to the last question. Use your current affiliation when you register on arXiv. That way people can contact you where you are now, and not get confused trying to contact you where you used to be. In the text of your thesis, acknowledge where the work was done. If the text of the thesis has an email address to reach you, be sure that email address still works.

Thank you for your response! Yes, an email address is added to the text of the thesis but this is the old email address (which still works) and includes the details of the former institution. So if I understand correctly for the thesis itself it would be preferred to enter the new email address + details within the author section and include an acknowledgement somewhere in the text? Thank you in advance

If both email addresses work then it doesn't matter whch you use. You are still overthinking things. For affiliation make it your CURRENT affiliation so people can find you.
